# Variable per page in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay

I have this project with Liferay where I manage courses for a training center. So I'll have a bunch of portlets for creating courses, a year schedule, teachers, etc.

And then I have a series of screens & portlets where you can manage and monitor the evolution of a specific course. So basically I have like two hierarchical sections of a website where you can create the entities in one, and manage a specific entity in other.

What I want to have is these two sections clearly separated, this way:

[image]

So in the course section all my portlets and the navigation menu are dependant of a "global" parameter which is the selected course identifier.

But I am new at Liferay and I am struggling with something that I'm sure it's fairly easy -- how can I pass this `courseId` parameter through all my dependant portlets? Sort of like a global variable for that context only?

In a normal website I would just append the parameter in the URL and I'll be fine but having many portlets in this section I'm sure there's gotta be a better way than passing the parameter to every single one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a few ways to do this are mentioned in the wiki [here](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portlet+to+Portlet+Communication).
This basically shows 3 ways of doing it.

1. Using Session
2. Using Events
3. Using Cookies

Kindly go through the wiki link, it should equip you with the right ways to do that.
HTH

Comment: The second one should be IPC mechanism, which again has 3 ways to do it: a) Events b) Public render parameters c) client side IPC.

Comment: Yeah, the wiki link mentioned has examples for all 3.

Comment: Thanks, I will try them all but will any of these screw the interaction on a multi-user scenario? Like, I send an event with the courseId and all users currently connected would see that course?

Comment: Event Inter-Portlet Communication is what you need. Section 2.2 . Only the portlets who are registered for that event will receive the event. Having said that, you can always pass some business logic parameters that prevent interference in a multi-user scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There is another possibility: jsr168 specified that you can have multiple public render parameter.

They are mapped into portlet.xml and if you use them you will receive values specified in url transparently.

You will find usage of these parameters into asset publisher portlet, for example, where public render parameter are used to listen user choice in category or tags navigation portlet.

Check out the jsr168/jsr286 portlet specification to find a way to manage them! ;)